# ForEach loop not finishing list

Tags: powershell, foreach

So I have an array of hostnames and I want run the command "Shutdown-VMGuest" on 45 host. I would like to turn off 20 at a time however when I get 40 done but it misses the last 5. This is the code below, does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

```
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$currentStartList = @()

    $i=0
    foreach ($vmHost in $PowerOffList){
        $i++
        [void]$currentstartList.Add($vmHost)
        if ($i -gt "19"){
            $vmToPowerOff = Get-VM -Name $currentstartList
            $Confirmation= Read-Host "`n Do you want to hard powerdown the following VMs (y/n)? $currentstartList"
            if ($Confirmation -eq 'y'){
                Write-Output "`n Trying to power down VMs safely: $vmToPowerOff"
                try {
                    Shutdown-VMGuest $vmToPowerOff
                }
                catch {
                    Write-Output "`n $vmToPowerOff has failed to power off safely"
                    $FailedVMs.Add($vmToPowerOff)
                }

                #clear lists
                [System.Collections.ArrayList]$currentstartList = @()
                $i=0
                sleep 5
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this need to run on PowerShell 2.0?

Comment: Currently using the current version

Comment: As an aside: while `$i -gt "19"` happens to work, because the numeric LHS forces the interpretation of the RHS as numeric too, it's confusing and unnecessary to use a _string_ as the RHS - just use `$i -gt 19`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this kind of thing I'd suggest using a `for` loop instead:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $PowerOffList.Count; $i += 20){
    # grab the next 20 (or fewer) hosts
    $currentStartList = $PowerOffList[$i..($i + 19)]

    # prompt user to start the hosts here
}
```

When you pass an array of index values to the `[]` index accessor in PowerShell, it simply ignores indices that don't exist, so the 3rd time the loop executes, `$PowerOffList[$i..($i + 19)]` will simply result in the last 5 items

Comment: @NW_92 Awesome. Consider marking an answer "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left!

Answer (score 2):

For the last 5 VMs, your variable `$i` will be stuck at `5` and your program will never get through this condition `if ($i -gt "19")`